# Formatar Button CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e gostaria de deixar meus button com dois visuais.Um button com entrar e outro button mais comprido mas com o mesmo visual, mesma cor, e a largura maior.
Mas não estou conseguindo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olhem como esta os  buttons

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  <button type="button" onclick="login()" class="entrar" >Entrar</button>  <button type="button" onclick="" class="esqueceu" >Esqueceu a Senha?</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É só você ir trabalhando propriedade por propriedade do CSS até ficar com algo parecido.

Aqui vai um começo.

```css
.btn {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13;
  width: 165px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #0066b8;
  padding: 9px 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

.btn-large {
  width: 340px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Entrar</button>

<hr style="margin: 10px 0" />

<button class="btn btn-large">Próximo</button>
```